# Dart Block for Language Server is flashing. VsCode is also slowed on Mac

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

This code Block section for Flutter/Dart code on VSCode keeps flashing. I have also been experiencing slow VSCode issues and I'm wondering if the two are related. Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening? my VSCode was fine before I updated flutter. It's only happening on one project and the rest work fine.

Tried looking for answers online, restarting VSCode, reinstalling, re-downloading project from git and nothing worked. Done a flutter upgrade and VSCode upgrade recently.

Comment: what's flashing? the `{}` icon in the status bar to the left of the language mode indicator?

Comment: Hi Sorry for the late response @starball, the {} icon is flashing a lot and so is the box above that is displayed in the image. My VSCode is also slow whenever I try run my app and the terminal gets slowed down drastically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete and reinstall flutter and VSCode as well as any references to them, including .dart, .dartServer and .flutter files as well as .vscode. Don't know what was wrong but I know that it fixed the issues I was having. Not sure how safe it is to delete so many files so wouldn't exactly recommend to someone unless you have some idea of what's happening and what files you do and don't need. Also update flutter.